# Gaussian Function in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need help making a program that calculates the Gaussian function `f(x)=1/(sqrt(2*pi)s)*exp[-.5*((x-m)/s)**2]` when `m=0`, `s=2`, and `x=1`.

Would it be just:

```
def Gaussian(m,s,x):
    return 1/(sqrt(2*pi)s)*exp[-.5*((x-m)/s)**2]
print Gaussian(0,2,1)
```

Comment: Have you tried it - did it give the correct results? You will need to import `sqrt`, `pi` and `exp` from the `math` module.

Comment: Why are you asking us, instead of trying it? I can see a few issues with your syntax (e.g. you need to use `*` to multiply by `s` and use parentheses to call the `exp` function), and you'll need to import `pi`, `sqrt` and `exp` from the standard library's `math` module, but those issues are not really worthy of a Stack Overflow question. If you've run the code you've shown and don't understand the errors you're getting, please include the full traceback of the exception in the question!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `from math import sqrt`, `from math import exp` and `from math import pi` unless you didn't show it in your code.